# Functions between metric spaces (and how they relate to closures of sets)

Tags: real-analysis, functions, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y , p)$ be metric spaces. Prove that if $f : X \to Y$ is continuous, then for any set $A\subset X$ with closure $\overline{A}$

- we have $f(\overline{A})\subset \overline{  f(A) }$
- give an example where $f(\overline{A})\ne \overline{  f(A) }$

Outline of my ideas for proof:

First, I would pick some $x\in\overline{A}$. This would mean $x$ is a limit point of $A$. Then I would show that because the function $f$ is continuous, the point $f(x)$ must be limit point of $f(A)$. Finally, since $f(x)$ is a limit point of $f(A)$, it must also be included in the closure of $f(A)$. QED

I'm not really sure about the example part though.

Answer (score 0):

For the example, take $X$ to be any non-closed subset of $Y$ endowed with the subspace topology (i.e., $d$ is $p$ restricted to $X$), and $f$ the inclusion map.

Comment: I see. So this example would work because the closure of a metric space is just the metric space itself, correct?

Comment: Yes. It has something to do with the fact that $X$ is not compact.

Answer (score 0):

Your plan for the first part looks good.

For the second part, there are counterexamples as described by Tunococ. However, there are also more substantial issues:

Let $0<\varepsilon_n<1$ be a sequence with $\varepsilon_n\to 0$, and define $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ by $f(x)=\cos(x)$. Finally, let $A=\{2\pi n - \varepsilon_n: n\geq 1\}$. Since $A$ is discrete it is closed, so $f(A)=f(\overline A)$. But $f(A)$ has zero as a limit point, which gives the desired inequality.

Note that these together suggest that neither injectivity nor surjectivity is sufficient; you may therefore reasonably suspect that bijectivity is not either. Can you construct an example, or prove the contrary?